# How to mathematically add two environment variables in Apache Config

Tags: apache

In an Apache config file, we have an environment variable that is dynamically set by the environment.

```
SetEnv foo ... // Some number
```

Later, we define a second environment variable that needs to be $foo + 1000

```
SetEnv bar ${foo}+1000
```

Sadly, this doesn't work. Is there a way to do this in pure Apache config?